# How to secure the content of .ipa file in ipad apps

Tags: iphone, ipad

my ipad app is in the final stages of development and we need to send the .ipa (build) files to various clients. Is there any way to secure the content in the ipa files so that no body can unzip the file and see the contents in it?? is there a way to secure the contents of the ipa???  Thank you...

Comment: Who are you trying to hide the contents from? If it's the clients, how are they meant to run the app if they can't open the bundle? I think this is going to suffer from the same issue as any other DRM implementation.

Comment: i am developing a ebook reader.. So , we send some books in the ipa as a sample... But, we want to secure those books in the ipa.... Can u help me with this plz

Comment: If the provided books are samples, why do you want to protect them ? Anyway, preventing unzipping the ipa might not be the solution. I would advice you to protect opening your ebooks. If your format is proprietary, it is a good but not sufficient protection. Otherwise, with PDF or ebook-like format, I guess you can prevent opening with an embedded protection mechanism.

Comment: @rockeye: hi, can yo please tell me a bit more on these mechanisms please.... is there any apple documentation regarding this..?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277506/how-to-protect-ios-bundle-files).

The best way to protect your data is to package them encrypted in a bundle.

Comment: @rockyeye:hi rockeye.. thanku for the inputs.. can u please explain me a bit more on embedded protection mechanism and encrypting a bundle mechanism...

Comment: I was talking about protection implemented inside the ebook format you might be using. Example : PDF opening can be protected. I guess other ebook formats provide such mechanisms. That what I meant by "embedded mechanisms". It is just a idea, as i don't work on that. Good luck