# How to secure .ipa?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipa

I want to know do we need to make `.ipa` file **secure**?

As We know , `.ipa` file of any app can be unzipped and contents of that file can be viewed and extracted easily. But What if we want to prevent this thing?

In Android , they use `encrypt/decrypt` to make secure `.apk` file.

So, how to do this thing for **iOS**?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943874/how-to-secure-the-content-of-ipa-file-in-ipad-apps?rq=1) is same question but without solution.

I have searched a lot but could not get any guide or tutorial for this.

Please help me for this.

Thanks.....

Comment: I do not think that this is possible, since iOS does not support this. Thus when you encrypt the file iOS will not be able to decrypt it.

Comment: @rckoenes - Ok. So do we need to secure the .ipa?

Comment: Well yes and no, any assets of you file are stored in the ipa unencrypted and easily accessable. But you code is compiled and not easily decompiled as with java.

Comment: @rckoenes Ok then how to secure unencrypted contents i.e assets of ipa?

Comment: Well you could encrypt the files before building the IPA, but then you  will have to decrypt then at run time which may results in a slower and less responsive app, since the decrypting will add some overhead. What kind of assets are there in you app that might be interesting to other people?

Comment: @Rohan, each asset could be individually encrypted, or put into a zip and that encrypted, then all decrypted within your code, but it all seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @rckoenes - Actually I am asking this question for the general apps. For which sometimes we need to protect/ prevent assets of app.

Comment: @JamesWebster - Thanks for guide. How to do this encrypt/decrypt process ? Please provide any tutorial or code if you have.

Comment: @Rohan, Unfortunately I don't know how to do that bit confidently enough. Even if I did however, that sort of question isn't suitable to ask here. You should be asking `What is wrong with my solution?` NOT `What is the solution?` We don't just provide code on demand.

Answer (score 2):

For users to install the IPA, it cannot be encrypted or protected in any way. App Store apps are protected with Apple's FairPlay DRM mechanism, but there is no way to apply this yourself, and it is possible to remove this protection.

If you are trying to protect the assets (images, videos) in your app, this isn't feasible. You just have to trust the people who have access to the app. You can try to obfuscate data or decrypt it at runtime, but if the user is going to see it on the screen, they can always find a way to get it out.

Comment: I'm afraid xibs are visible too, info plist as well. This should not be this way from apple. Can't do anything except trust.